# Horizontal accordion

Tags: html, css, layout

I try to accomplish this:

[image]

But I can't get the third column and the flipped headers correct.

This is how I have it now:

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/6TnaD/2/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution works in IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera and doesn’t require JavaScript or images.
This is done with `CSS3 :target selector`
hope this will help you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z68Zz/)

Comment: The :target selector can be used to style the current active target element. Please check here. Thank you. http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: Is it possible to load the content dynamically?
So that for example the content of the links are loaded after a click?
Click link1 = load content from php file (wordpress)

Comment: you can change the contents section to what ever you what :)

Comment: yes I know, but every page has a lot of content. If I load all the content of those pages in 1 html file, then it would require a lot of resources. I'm using Wordpress.